# Why it says " List contains no element matching the predicate." for android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have Onboarding Screens for my project, and it work correctly, but I want to show users it just once, and I was using shared preferences for it, and when debug the project it is throw an error like that in logcat,

> List contains no element matching the predicate.

, and in android emulator I can see main screen, but app crash quickly, when I open app again on simulator, onboarding screen shows just 1 second and open main screen, than app crash, I do not know why? I guess problem is because of this line of code,

```
if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
                    navController.navigate("main")
                }else{
```

but I am not sure.

**mainscreen:**

```
@Composable
 fun MainScreen(
     navController: NavController,

 ) {

     
     Column(
         Modifier
             .fillMaxSize()

         ,
         horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
     ) {

      Text(
                     "WELCOME TO",
                     modifier = Modifier
                         .width(300.dp)

                     ,
                     textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                     fontSize = 15.sp,
                     color = custom,
                     fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium

                 )
}
```

**nav:**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun NavScreen(
    sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) {


    val navController = rememberNavController()


    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "onBoard") {

        composable("onBoard",  ) {

            OnBoardScreen(navController = navController, sharedPreferences)
        }
        composable("main") {
            MainScreen(navController = navController)
        }
}
```

**viewmodel:**

```
class OnBoardViewModel (

)  : ViewModel() {
    private val _currentPage = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val currentPage: StateFlow<Int> get() = _currentPage

    fun setCurrentPage(currentPage: Int) {
        _currentPage.value = currentPage
    }

}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(

) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       
        setContent {
            CustomTheme {
                    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("onBoardingScreen", MODE_PRIVATE)

                        NavScreen(sharedPreferences)
                }
             }
         }
     }
   }



@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun OnBoardScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    val onBoardViewModel : OnBoardViewModel = viewModel()
    val currentPage = onBoardViewModel.currentPage.collectAsState()


    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        pageCount = onBoardItem.size,
        initialOffscreenLimit = 2,
        initialPage = 0,
        infiniteLoop = false
    )

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        ) {

            if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
                navController.navigate("main")
            }else{
                val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false)
                editor.apply()
            }

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                onBoardViewModel.currentPage
                    .collect {
                        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(
                            page = currentPage.value
                        )
                    }
            }

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(
                        brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                            colors = listOf(
                                white,
                                grey
                            )
                        )
                    )
            ) {
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    HorizontalPager(
                        state = pagerState
                    ) { page ->
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(top = 60.dp)
                                .fillMaxWidth(),
                            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                        ) {

                            Text(
                                text = onBoardItem[page].desc,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(30.dp),
                                color = custom,
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

                            Image(
                                painter = painterResource(id = onBoardItem[page].image),
                                contentDescription = "OnBoardImage",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .height(500.dp)
                                    .fillMaxWidth(),

                            )

                        }
                    }

                    PagerIndicator(onBoardItem.size, pagerState.currentPage)
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                ) {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(bottom = 30.dp)
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = if (pagerState.currentPage != 2 ) {
                            Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                        } else {
                            Arrangement.Center
                        }
                    ) {
                        if (pagerState.currentPage == 2) {

                            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Start",
                                color = custom,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(start = 280.dp, bottom = 40.dp)

                                    .clickable {
                                        navController.navigate("main")


                                    },
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium


                            )
                        }

                        } else {
                            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Skip",
                                color = custom,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(start = 25.dp, bottom = 42.dp)
                                    .clickable {
                                        navController.navigate("main")

                                    },
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            )
                        }

                            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {
                            Text(
                                text = "Next",
                                color = custom,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .clickable {
                                        onBoardViewModel.setCurrentPage(pagerState.currentPage + 1)
                                    }
                                    .padding(end = 25.dp, bottom = 42.dp),
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            )
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun PagerIndicator(size: Int, currentPage: Int) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 40.dp)
    ) {
        repeat(size) {
            IndicateIcon(
                isSelected = it == currentPage
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun IndicateIcon(isSelected: Boolean) {
    val width = animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (isSelected) 10.dp else 10.dp
    )

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(2.dp)
            .height(10.dp)
            .width(width.value)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(
                if (isSelected) custom else customColor
            )
    )
}
```

Comment: That is a *lot* of code to read through and you didn't say where the error is...

Comment: @Tenfour04, I mention above about error, app crashed and I just see on log cat this error "List contains no element matching the predicate."

Comment: Usually when you get a crash you also get an error message with a stack trace in Logcat. In Android Studio you can open the Logcat tab and check for the stacktrace there (make sure the selected "device" is your simulator). Based on the wording in the message the cause is more likely a list on which a function with a predicate is called, such as `first {...}`, `find {...}`, `last {...}` etc., and since that list is empty an exception is thrown. It might be in your code or in some platform code you are calling. But finding that stacktrace will show you exactly where the crash starts.

Comment: @Ma3x, it says `"at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)"` for this line of code `val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("onBoardingScreen", MODE_PRIVATE)`

Comment: @SpaceDevs Can you update your question with the code of the MainScreen composable as well, please.

Comment: @Ma3x I update question

Comment: @SpaceDevs I identified a potential problem with your code, now that might be the cause for the error you are seeing or not. See my answer below, if that does not prevent the error, please update your question with the whole stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are calling `navController.navigate("main")` during composition while not ensuring that it is called only once when the navigation should happen, thus creating a situation where `navController.navigate("main")` is called repeatedly in quick succession. I think that might be the cause and the exception might be the effect.

Wrap the navigation call (that is now directly part of the composition) into a LaunchedEffect

```
    if (!sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            navController.navigate("main")
        }
    } else {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false)
        editor.apply()
    }
```

Comment: tnx so much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For those using alpha version of the dependency, you can try downgrading the version to stable version.

I was using Dagger Hilt for navigation using this dependency `implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01'`. So I downgraded it to `implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'`

If you are using `implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0-rc01"`, then you can downgrade it to `implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.2"`